# How to convert lidocaine hydrochloride to lidocaine base?

Tags: acid-base, solubility, home-experiment, medicinal-chemistry, amides

I'm a hobbyist, no pro. I've got a formulation for a topical anesthetic I'm trying to mimic. It calls for lidocaine, ethoxydiglycol (also known as diethylene glycol monoethyl ether) and a couple of oils.

I've read that lidocaine HCl is soluble in water and insoluble in ether, whereas lidocaine base is soluble in ether, but not in water. Based on that, I'm concerned I won't be able to mix my lidocaine HCl with the ethoxydiglycol, and I need lidocaine base instead of the lidocaine HCl I've got on hand.

I'm planning to dissolve the lidocaine HCl in distilled water, then add baking soda to it until the pH drops low enough for lidocaine base to precipitate.  After that, I plan to filter the whole thing through a coffee filter, rinse with more distilled water, then evaporate the water off.  I'm hoping this will yield pure lidocaine base that I can work with.

Will it work? Are their any caveats I should know about?

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/87644/nahco3-required-to-raise-ph-of-weak-hcl-solution-from-3-5-to-7-2-doubting-my-ca

Comment: Have you checked the maximum concentration levels of carbitol to ensure no adverse effects, for topical applications?